# Excel dynamic data series. Unusual data look and chart

Tags: excel, charts

Since I solved previous problem with collecting data from database, I need to put that data on a chart now. I am working on a report generating software called ReportWorx. 
Problem is, data comes in series and looks like this:

```
ID    DATE        SAMPLE  
1     XX-XX-XX    VALUE  
1     XX-XX-XX    VALUE  
1     XX-XX-XX    VALUE  
2     XX-XX-XX    VALUE  
2     XX-XX-XX    VALUE  
3     XX-XX-XX    VALUE  
3     XX-XX-XX    VALUE
```

I can not change how it looks because it is generated automatically. What I want is linear chart in which 1, 2, 3 are series name and of course next to it DATE and VALUE are put on a linear chart (or bargraph, w/e) (Date at X axis, Value at Y axis).

I can`t specify how many records will be there (how many rows) but I found few solutions about creating dynamically increasing charts, so probably it will not be a poblem. I just do not know how to separate thos ID series from each other.

EDIT:
I have found a solution in VBA according to the first answer. Here you have VBA code below:

```
Sub Rewrite()
Dim row, id
For row = 38 To 1000
    For id = 1 To 37
        If Sheet1.Cells(row, 1).Value = id Then
            Sheet2.Cells(row, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(row, 2)
            Sheet2.Cells(row, id + 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(row, 3)
        End If
    Next id
Next row
End Sub
```

Thank You @sancho.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post a solution that I use a lot for cases like yours.

[image]
[image]

With reference to the figure (where I used sample numbers), you set up 3 new columns (D:F here), the header of which contain the corresponding labels. Then you use a formula for "splitting" the list of X data (column B here) associated with each label, and assigning a "NULL" value for data not corresponding (`#N/A` here, but you can choose whatever you want):

```
=IF($A3=D$2,$B3,$B$1)
```

You enter this in D3. The absolute/relative indexing used allows for copy-and-paste throughout D3:F9.
Cell B1 here contains the "NULL" value.
Then you plot 3 series: column C against columns D, E, F.

PS: I guess you could split the Y data column instead, with similar results. For some reason that I do not recall, I decided a long time ago that this was the best option, at least in my case then. You may want to try out the other option.

PS2: This also works for data that is not sorted by label.

PS3: Using `NA()` as the "NULL" value avoids cell values being taken as zero and then showing up in the chart, as it is the case with other errors (e.g., try using `=1/0` in B1). It is the best option I found so far. Alternatively (just in case you find it useful), you can use an explicit value which is outside the actual X data range, but then you would have to manually set the X axis range. All this is for a Scatter plot, just check what works for your case.

Comment: @pnuts - Yes, you may use `NA()` directly in the formula instead of `$B$1`, but I found it useful to have the option of changing the "NULL" value at once, for different purposes that I do not recall. It probably doesn't bother, anyway. I also ruled out a PivotChart, perhaps for Scatter plots (as I use), or because the solution posted is automatically updated (when you add a series, import data from a file, etc.), or... ? You only have to copy-paste in the target range.

Comment: Your solution is great, but my case seems to be more complicated. My data range is not specified anywhere. If user checks 2 months or 2 days range, it will just dynamically expand and add rows. Additionally, script used by report provider (db connector) changes formulas to avoid using those dynamically axpandable rows. Well I think I will need to use some VBA function, because this dynamic rows breaks functions typed even in this way $B$2 and instead of first row I connects it with last dynamic row+1.

Do You have any VBA solution for this?

Comment: @PawełCzech - I did not fully understand the procedure you have to apply to go from your input data to the chart, and I do not know how many of these you will be producing, but the method posted should work. You may need some extra work to setup you input data in the basic table, copy formulas as needed, and produce the charts, but that is a separate issue (probably needed whatever alternative solution you use for the question posed). I recommend you record a macro while performing these actions manually, and check the resulting code.

Comment: @PawełCzech - You will hardly avoid reading a bit about this. Google "excel vba record macro" (get, e.g., http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-how-to-excel-macro-recorder.html), it should get you started.

Comment: I have been reading about this since 2 hours already. Problem is I have close deadline (tomorrow). I am helping friend at work to finish the job before this deadline, so asked for any solutions. I already started to try some scripts. Greetings:)

Comment: I have written script to do exact thing You suggested. Here is the code if anyone needs it in a future: 
`Sub Rewrite()
    Dim row, id
    For row = 38 To 1000
        For id = 1 To 37
            If Sheet1.Cells(row, 1).Value = id Then
                Sheet2.Cells(row, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(row, 2)
                Sheet2.Cells(row, id + 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(row, 3)
            End If
        Next id
    Next row
End Sub
`
I set maximum rows to 1000 and maximum ID to 37 (this is my case).